# PHP trying to work with classes, but class can't be accessed

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a class with a function in one php file, and the access it from another. But I can't get it to work. I get `Fatal error: Class 'databaseConnect' not found`.

The code:

```
    <?php
        $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "usbw", "beoordelingen") or die(mysql_error());

        class database {
            public function getDatabase($theVar, $theSelector,  $theLocator) {
                $theVar = $conn->query("SELECT $theSelector FROM beoordeling $theLocator");
            }
        }

    ?>
```

Then trying to call it in another file:

```
<?php
        include("myClassFile.php");

            $index = new database();

            $index->getDatabase($result, "DISTINCT `category`");
?>
```

Does it have something to do with scope or namespace? Or am I just doing something wrong here.

Comment: File is not included properly. If you're doing `include("myClassFile.php");` then make sure that both the files are in the same directory.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul They are in the same directory.

Comment: Just to make sure... you do have `<?php` in the top of the myClassFile.php-file as well?

Comment: Is it a typo - you didn't close `"`?

Comment: @u_mulder that's a typo yes.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes I have `<?php` in the first line.

Comment: Then fix the error @u_mulder pointed out and test again.

Comment: That was only a typo here, I deleted some of the statement when I posted it.

Comment: Then you should post the ACTUAL code that doesn't work. A pseudo-copy doesn't really help us debugging it for you.

Comment: Is the file loaded at all? Have a look in the web server's error log. Use `require` instead of `include` to see if it loads. If not check your include path. If it does post the real code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson The code actually isn't any different. Accept for the arguments. So I thought lets not place too much unusefull information. Anyway, I edited the post..

Comment: @some-non-descript-user It loads. For sure. Since I can still put anything in my  `myClassFile.php` like a `$testVar = 10` and then echo it on the index page where I include (and tried require) `myClassFile.php`. No problems. But when I start making class it seems to be broken somehow.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with the code you posted. The error must be somewhere else.

Comment: It may be a dumb question but I want to be be clear. Seems like `$conn` isn't defined anywhere in your code. From where do you get it?

Comment: @rehmat I declared it before defining what the class looks like. I'll upload the complete code.

Comment: @Dennis1679 yes upload the complete code otherwise we will not be able to find out what's going wrong actually. In current code, there isn't anything wrong except some undefined properties.

Comment: I get this now: `Notice: Undefined variable: var in index.php on line 9` `Notice: Undefined variable: conn in myClassFile.php on line 8`

Comment: Variables aren't global in PHP. So `$conn` won't be accessable within your class. You need to either use `global $conn` in your class method (globals are bad, though) or pass it through the constructor/method.

Comment: I think you should start by reading some tutorials about the basics of PHP

Comment: You are not defining any class `databaseConnect` whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

(1) check whether the file exists. you'd better use absolute path as well.

(2) whether there is a namespace scope. try new \databaseConnect();  append a back-slash

Comment: Checked both and the file exists, see my previous comment. And also appending a back-slash didn't do the trick.

Comment: add `var_dump('::::::::calling::::::::::'); $db = new database();` at the end of myClassFile.php,  and run to check whether the '::::::::calling::::::::::' displays. Then you may find out the resolution.